# How to write data to excel with header using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write the excel file with the header is
[image]

I have data and I want to fill out the excel file. Then the expected result is
[image]

This is my code but it does not show as my expected. Could you help me to fix it? Thanks

```
from pandas import DataFrame
id =['1','2']
width_man=['12','18']
height_man=['20','55']
age_man=['10','12']
width_woman=['15','11']
height_woman=['40','45']
age_woman=['11','15']

df = DataFrame({'ID': id, 'WIDTH': width_man, 'HEIGHT': height_man, 'AGE': age_man, 'WIDTH': width_woman, 'HEIGHT': height_woman, 'AGE': age_woman,})
df.to_excel('table.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

THIS IS OUTPUT OF MY CODE

[image]

Comment: The data you have in your example doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: It matched. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below method,

```py
import pandas as pd

id =['1','2']
width_man=['12','18']
height_man=['20','55']
age_man=['10','12']
width_woman=['15','11']
height_woman=['40','45']
age_woman=['11','15']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': id, 'WIDTH': width_man, 'HEIGHT': height_man, 'AGE': age_man})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': id, 'WIDTH': width_woman, 'HEIGHT': height_woman, 'AGE': age_woman})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('table.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, index=False) 
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=1,
             startcol=5, index=False)
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.write_string(0, 2, 'MAN')
worksheet.write_string(0, 6, 'WOMAN')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. How about header man and woman in middle of the row. It looks works

Comment: What does it mean 0, 2, and 0,6?

Comment: @KimHee (row - 0, column -2) & (row -0, column 6). Thank you for marking it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should a multi-level index in Pandas to structure your data so that it matches your desired output:

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame({'WIDTH': width_man, 'HEIGHT': height_man, 'AGE': age_man, },index=id)
dfw = pd.DataFrame({'WIDTH': width_woman, 'HEIGHT': height_woman, 'AGE': age_woman,},index=id)
df = pd.concat([dfm,dfw],axis=1,keys=['man','woman'])
df.to_excel('table.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=True, index_label='id')
```

I've also changed id to the index since you're clearly using it as the index.

(The format of the excel file has some small differences to your desired output - no blank column between "man" and "woman", and "id" as the index label is on a separate line. However the point remains that by using Pandas to structure the data correctly the spreadsheet generates correctly and automatically)